# Compiler Keeps Timing out for Tikz Graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, compiling

```
\usetikzlibrary{fit,positioning,arrows,automata}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows,shapes}
\usepackage{mhchem}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\let\ce\ch

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm,minimum size=1cm,]
    

\node[circle, draw=black] (A) at (1,2) {$X_{{t-1}}$};
\node[circle,draw=black] (B) at (-0.5,0) {$e_{t^{-}}$};
\node[circle,draw=black] (C) at (2,0) {$O_{t^{-}}$};
\node[circle, draw = black] (D) at (5,2) {$X_t$}
\node[circle, draw = black] (E) at (4,0) {$X_t$}
\node[circle, draw = black] (F) at (6,0) {$X_t$}
\node[circle, draw = black] (G) at (8,2) {$X_{t+1}$}
\node[circle, draw = black] (H) at (7,0) {$X_t$}
\node[circle, draw = black] (I) at (9,0) {$X_t$}

\draw [->] (A) -- (B);
\draw [->] (A) -- (C);
\draw [->] (A) -- (D)

    
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The compiler just keeps timing out when I try to run this in Latex. Im completely new to using Tikz and trying to draw a figure. Does anyone see what could be wrong?

Comment: You need to put a `;` at the end of all `\node` and `\draw` lines.

Comment: A complete answer to your original question has been posted in the original topic: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/583389/how-can-i-draw-this-dynamic-markov-model-figure-in-latex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

welcome to TeX StackExchange!

The problem with your code is that you forgot to end each `\node` by ';' (and also on your last `\draw`).

Your code should look like this:

```
\usetikzlibrary{fit,positioning,arrows,automata}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows,shapes}
\usepackage{mhchem}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\let\ce\ch

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm,minimum size=1cm,]
    \node[circle, draw=black] (A) at (1,2) {$X_{{t-1}}$};
    \node[circle,draw=black] (B) at (-0.5,0) {$e_{t^{-}}$};
    \node[circle,draw=black] (C) at (2,0) {$O_{t^{-}}$};
    \node[circle, draw = black] (D) at (5,2) {$X_t$};
    \node[circle, draw = black] (E) at (4,0) {$X_t$};
    \node[circle, draw = black] (F) at (6,0) {$X_t$};
    \node[circle, draw = black] (G) at (8,2) {$X_{t+1}$};
    \node[circle, draw = black] (H) at (7,0) {$X_t$};
    \node[circle, draw = black] (I) at (9,0) {$X_t$};

    \draw [->] (A) -- (B);
    \draw [->] (A) -- (C);
    \draw [->] (A) -- (D);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Which gives:
[image]